# ROS2 two instances of joy_node with same controller type

Tags: ros2, joystick, joy-node

I am trying to move two robots with two joy sticks connected to the same PC. Both Xbox Series X Controllers are correctly registered at `/dev/input/js0` and `/dev/input/js1`, respectively. I tested both joy sticks with `sudo jstest /dev/input/js0` and `sudo jstest /dev/input/js01`, which correctly shows the buttons are triggered on the respective device.

It doesn't matter how I start instances of either teleop_twist_joy_node, or joy_node with remappings, separate node names, etc. (I have tried every possible combination). One controller will always publish data on both joy topics. The other never triggers any publishing of data on any joy topic.

I assume it is connected to the joystick being of the same model. The output `ros2 run joy joy_enumerate_devices` is as follows:

```
ID : GUID                             : GamePad : Mapped : Joystick Device Name
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 0 : 060000005e040000120b000009050000 :    true :  false : Xbox Series X Controller
 1 : 060000005e040000120b000009050000 :    true :  false : Xbox Series X Controller
```

Is there any way to fix this issue and use two joysticks of the same type on the same machine for moving two robots?